# Telnet log parser

Tags: parser, telnet

I've set up a telnet honeypot and I'm looking for a library that could pull the IP address out of this:

```
[2021-02-22 10:28:06] [127.0.0.1:46368] AUTH: bog:bog
[2021-02-22 10:28:12] [127.0.0.1:46368] AUTH: :^]
[2021-02-22 10:28:13] [127.0.0.1:46368] AUTH: :
[2021-02-22 10:28:13] [127.0.0.1:46368] SESSION_END
```

Something in Python would be nice, but any language works.

Comment: On *nix you could just use `awk`, `sed`, `cut`, `grep` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python re built in library, *possibly with the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) or [grin](https://pypi.org/project/grin3/) packages,* looks good.

To get all of the unique IP addresses you could use something like:

```
import re

ip_addresses = set(re.findall(r'((?:[\d]{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})', open('file.log').read())
print(ip_addresses)
```

Adding the verbose flag to make things more readable:

```
import re

ip_addresses = set(re.findall(r'''
( # Capture Group
(?: # Non Capture Group
\d  # Digit
{1,3} # Between 1 & 3 times
\. # Literal .
) # End Non Capture Group
{3} # Repeat exactly 3 times
\d # Digit
{1,3} # Between 1 & 3 times
) # End capture group
''', open('file.log').read(), re.VERBOSE)

print(ip_addresses)
```

Of course you could use glob or argparse to make this into a utility script.